# While loop stopping without apparent reason

Tags: c, loops

I have the following C code:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(int argc, const char *argv[]){
    const char *directory_path;
    directory_path = argv[1];
    char *dirname;
    dirname = strdup(directory_path);
    recursive_ls(dirname);

}


int recursive_ls(char *dirname){
    printf("%s\n",dirname);
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;

    if ((d=opendir(dirname))==-1) {
        perror("Oops");
        return(0);
    }
    if(d){
        while((dir = readdir(d)) !=NULL){
            char *dname = dir->d_name;
            puts(dname);
/*          if(strcmp(dir->d_type,DT_REG)){
                puts("I am a regular file");
            } else if(strcmp(dir->d_type,DT_DIR)){
                puts("I am a directory.");
                            recursive_ls(strcat(strcat(dirname,"/"),dir->d_name));
                } else {
                    puts("I am not a file");
            }
*/    
        }

        closedir(d);
    }
return(0);
}
```

if I comment out the `if(){} else if(){} else(){}` inside the while loop, I get the following output:

```
Debug
.project
pipe_test.c
.
..
```

Which is everything in the directory. If on the other hand, I uncomment it, then I get the following:

```
/home/wilbert/workspace/pipe_test
.cproject
```

I figure I should at least get the "I am not a file" part if everything if the recursive step is screwing things up; however, for some reason I don't so I am puzzled. The thing compiles and shows no syntactic  errors so I am really puzzled. Why is this happening?

Comment: Remember that `strcmp` returns `0` when strings are equal

Comment: @AlterMann why don't you post as the answer?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, you are right!! its an unsigned char

Answer (score 4):

As Jonathon suggest `d_type` is an `unsigned char`, so change to:

```
if(dir->d_type == DT_REG){
   puts("I am a regular file");
} else if(dir->d_type == DT_DIR){
   puts("I am a directory.");
   recursive_ls(strcat(strcat(dirname,"/"),dir->d_name));
} else {
   puts("I am not a file");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `d_type` member of `struct dirent` is not a string (`char *`), but an `unsigned char`. This is really just an 8 bit integer, which is a primitive type. When comparing primitive types we use the `==` operator. `strcmp` is strictly for comparing strings.

```
if (dir->d_type == DT_REG) {
   puts("I am a regular file");
} else if (dir->d_type == DT_DIR) {
   puts("I am a directory.");
   recursive_ls(strcat(strcat(dirname,"/"),dir->d_name));
} else {
   puts("I am not a file");
}
```

See the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Directory-Entries.html) for more info.

And, even though your original code compiles without errors, it gives lots of warnings when you include the commented body. A good tip is to always consider compiler warnings as bugs.